# displaying the name of classes that java compiler is executing

Tags: java

i am working on a project that contains lots of packages and each package contains lots of classes. when i run class that contains the main method, i dont know which class is actually executed and involved in my work. is there is any way that i can track which classes the compiler visited or is there any code i can put at the end of the main method that shows the name of classes that have been executed.

I tried to find properties of the compiler that help me to track its path but i did not find any thing

i am using Eclipse

Comment: You can make use of AspectJ to write method interceptors. In interceptors you can log class and method name. https://www.baeldung.com/aspectj

Comment: "is there is any way that i can track which classes the compiler visited" Depending on how you're building your project, the compiler will either visit all the classes that have been changed since the last build or all the classes period. However, that has nothing to do with which code will or won't be executed at runtime.

Comment: https://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/01/aop-aspectj-java-method-logging.html
This link is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: AspectJ requires me to create a new AspectJ project, i did that then i copied all the packages and past them in the AspectJ project, but i got errors especially with importing packages like java.util, it did not acknowledge them

Answer (score -1):

This is actually something called reflection. there are methods you can run to see all of your Java classes in your project. All though i myself don't know how to see all the classes that run on a specific run you can see all the class on your project every time you run with reflection and i am sure there is a way to use it for doing what you want.

read the Reflection documantion and added a little snippet that shows you how you can use Reflection to view many things like Methods/Classes and many more things in your java project.

```
// Creating object whose property is to be checked 
        Test obj = new Test(); 

        // Creating class object from the object using 
        // getclass method 
        Class cls = obj.getClass(); 
        System.out.println("The name of class is " + 
                            cls.getName()); 

        // Getting the constructor of the class through the 
        // object of the class 
        Constructor constructor = cls.getConstructor(); 
        System.out.println("The name of constructor is " + 
                            constructor.getName()); 

        System.out.println("The public methods of class are : "); 

        // Getting methods of the class through the object 
        // of the class by using getMethods 
        Method[] methods = cls.getMethods(); 

        // Printing method names 
        for (Method method:methods) 
            System.out.println(method.getName()); 

        // creates object of desired method by providing the 
        // method name and parameter class as arguments to 
        // the getDeclaredMethod 
        Method methodcall1 = cls.getDeclaredMethod("method2", 
                                                 int.class); 

        // invokes the method at runtime 
        methodcall1.invoke(obj, 19); 

        // creates object of the desired field by providing 
        // the name of field as argument to the  
        // getDeclaredField method 
        Field field = cls.getDeclaredField("s"); 

        // allows the object to access the field irrespective 
        // of the access specifier used with the field 
        field.setAccessible(true); 

        // takes object and the new value to be assigned 
        // to the field as arguments 
        field.set(obj, "JAVA"); 

        // Creates object of desired method by providing the 
        // method name as argument to the getDeclaredMethod 
        Method methodcall2 = cls.getDeclaredMethod("method1"); 

        // invokes the method at runtime 
        methodcall2.invoke(obj); 

        // Creates object of the desired method by providing 
        // the name of method as argument to the  
        // getDeclaredMethod method 
        Method methodcall3 = cls.getDeclaredMethod("method3"); 

        // allows the object to access the method irrespective  
        // of the access specifier used with the method 
        methodcall3.setAccessible(true); 

        // invokes the method at runtime 
        methodcall3.invoke(obj);
```

and the output of this is :

```
The name of class is Test
The name of constructor is Test
The public methods of class are : 
method2
method1
wait
wait
wait
equals
toString
hashCode
getClass
notify
notifyAll
The number is 19
The string is JAVA
Private method invoked
```

There are two setbacks tho to Reflection :

It takes time for the machine to process it like everything else in your code.
It Exposes Internal Methods and Class so i would recommend doing this only to test and View stuff you want to see then removing it.

Hope this sets you on the right track.

Comment: thanks for the help, dis you mean putting this code at the end of my main method ??          i out it there, and it shows error under the Test, Method, Constructor names

Comment: You need to import those and Test is just a class name. Use one of yours

Comment: Thanks for the help, i tried importing Constructor, but i got this error -> Multiple markers at this line
 - Type safety: The method getConstructor(Class...) belongs to the raw type Class. References to generic type 
  Class<T> should be parameterized
 - Constructor cannot be resolved to a type